# matching data from one table to another with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering you can match data from one table to another (example below)

What if I wanted to link my second table to the first one and add the id of the city to my headline.

I guess I would need to something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM headlines where headline LIKE %$city%
```

And then do an insert everything time I got something returned. But then I would need to repeat my query for the hundred of cities I have every time I add a new headline.

```
    First Table (Cities) | Second Table (Headlines)
    ______________________________________________________
    id: 1 name: New-York | Something happened in New-York
    id: 2 name: LA       | Something else happened in LA
                         | Somehting happened in LA and New-York
```

Can anybody point me to whatever I should be looking into to do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, because you haven't explained the actual application of it... without understanding the application it's hard to say whether or not you should be doing something, since we need to be able to weigh our own approaches vs yours.

Comment: Are you saying that every time a headline is added (by a user? by who?) that it adds a new city to the city table?

Comment: The headlines would be scraped from different news websites. But I think Gordon's answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a `join` clause with  a `like` condition:

```
 SELECT h.*, c.cities
 FROM headlines h join
      cities c
      on h.headline like concat('%', c.city, '%')
```

The key is getting the wildcard parameters in the pattern, using `concat()`.

By the way, this will do a nest-loop query, which will not perform very well.  Because of the `like` condition, indexes will not help improve performance.

A better approach is to build a full text index on the `headline` column and use `match` for the comparison.  This will also help prevent conflicts like "London" matching "Londonderry".

And, in your example `LA` is particularly problematic, because many words contain `LA`.  You could try something like:

```
      on concat(' ', replace(replace(replace(h.headline, ',', ' '), ':', ' '), '.', ' '), ' ') like
               concat('% ', c.city, ' %')
```

That is, replace punctuation with spaces, add a space at the beginning and end of the headline, and then look for the city name surrounded by spaces.  This prevents a match between "LA" and "AtLAnta" (caps only for emphasis).

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail what you think is a better approach ? (I'm pretty new to MySQL)

Comment: @metareviewr . . . If you are doing a quick-and-dirty one-time comparison, getting `like` to work is fine.  If you want to do this multiple times, then consider a full text index.  The details are best left to the documentation . . . http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: I tried your query and it works fine but it seems to ignore when my city is in between apostrophes like so 'New-York'. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Apparently fulltext search won't take another column name as a parameter for AGAINST.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities";
$res_mysql=mysql_query($sql);  
   while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($res_mysql)){
      while(mysql_fetch_array($res_mysql_like)){
          $update= "UPDATE `Headlines` SET `id` ='".$arr[1]."'
          WHERE `headline LIKE %$arr[1]%";
      mysql_query($update)
      or die(mysql_error());
      }
   }
```

you need to select fisrt id fron city table and check if appear in headline table, then do the same white 2 id of table cities.

i hope this can help you, maybe i  didn't understand very well the problem, mi english level  isn't  very good.